# CSS :before & position: relative issue in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

### The problem

I am creating a `:before` pseudo-element and when its main element is `position: relative;` the following happens on IE, *all versions* – and I want the modern browser's effect:

[image: IE]

In Chrome (working):

[image: Chrome]

If you didn't understand well, I explain: the `overlay` is limited to the element itself when its position is relative in Internet Explorer. Chrome, Firefox and "modern browsers" at all works correctly.

To see an interactive example, I prepared to you [right here, in JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/28jHf/).

Note that **I really need** to get `button` positioned relatively.

### Code behind

**HTML:**

```
<button>Play</button>
```

**CSS:**

```
button {
    position: relative;
    margin: 250px;
}

button:before {
    background-color: green;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    content: 'Overlay';
    margin-left: -30px;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried simply adding overflow: visible to the button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `overflow: visible` to the button:

```
button {
    position: relative;
    margin: 250px;
    overflow: visible;
}
```